# PHP group in a multidimensional array by year and month from a 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is the array i retrieve from the server:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [IdEvent] => 5
            [EventName] => Copy of Opening snow weekend
            [Year] => 2012
            [Month] => 08
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [IdEvent] => 7
            [EventName] => Copy of Copy of Opening snow weekend
            [Year] => 2012
            [Month] => 07
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [IdEvent] => 1
            [EventName] => Opening snow weekend
            [Year] => 2011
            [Month] => 05
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [IdEvent] => 6
            [EventName] => Copy of Opening snow weekend
            [Year] => 2010
            [Month] => 05
        )

)
```

This is the resulting array that i need

```
Array
(
    [2012] => Array
        (
            [08] => Array
                  (
                       [IdEvent] => 5
                       [EventName] => Copy of Opening snow weekend
                  )

            [07] => Array
                  (
                       [IdEvent] => 7
                       [EventName] => Copy of Opening snow weekend
                  )
        )

    [2011] => Array
        (
            [05] => Array
                  (
                       [IdEvent] => 1
                       [EventName] => Copy of Opening snow weekend
                  )
        )

    [2010] => Array
        (
            [05] => Array
                  (
                       [IdEvent] => 6
                       [EventName] => Copy of Opening snow weekend
                  )
        )

)
```

I managed to group them by year using the following code:

```
        foreach($query->result_array() as $event){
        if(isset($data[$event['year']])){
            $data[$event['year']][] = $event['event'];
        } else {
            $data[$event['year']] = array($event['event']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You were so close, see Gautam3164 answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $event){
    if(isset($event['year'])){
        $data[$event['year']][$event['Month']]['IdEvent'] = $event['IdEvent'];
        $data[$event['year']][$event['Month']]['EventName'] = $event['EventName'];
    } else {
        $data[$event['year']] = array($event['event']);
    }
}
```

Or even you can try like

```
if(isset($event['year'])){
    $data[$event['year']][$event['Month']] = array( 'IdEvent' => $event['IdEvent'],
                                                    'EventName' => $event['EventName']);
}
```